# How do i relate model X to an instance of model X?

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend

Suppose i have

```
class modelX(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

now

```
var1 = modelX(value='some_value')
var2 = modelX(value='another_value')
```

How do i connect var1 and var2 ?

I know about .objects.all method but thats not what i want.
I want something like a linked list.

Comment: Do you mean like a foreign key? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: What about using a foreign key referencing to its own table with `related_x = models.ForeignKey("self")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a self referential foreign key.

```
class modelX(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self")
```

so you can connect two objects from the same model with a parent-children relation

```
var1 = modelX(value='some_value')
var2 = modelX(value='another_value', parent=var1)

print(var2.parent.value)
>>> "some_value"
```